# How can I embed information in a pdf file (created by plot)?

Tags: r, pdf, plot

I often use R to plot to pdf.

Years later, when a reader asks me how I made this figure, I then wonder what data version I used for exactly this plot.

So I would like to embed additional arbitrary information in a pdf file that is not used for anything---I don't want notes or annotation or etc.

For example,

```
y <- round( rnorm(20), 3)
pdf("/tmp/ab.pdf");
plot( y )
addpdfmetadata("created yesterday, with data ", y, "on host abc.edu")
dev.off()
```

Later, I will want to be able to inspect the raw pdf file with an editor and find my utf8 string.

the embedded information itself could be short (such as the output from file.info()) or long (such as the data used to generate the plot itself).  I also need to write a routine to extract the relevant comments.

So, is it possible to add non-functional text?

PS: I guess that the ability to put in some short acrobat reader like annotations would be nice, too, but I presume that this would require more finesse, and is a different question.

Comment: You could use custom metadata which you can see easier with file-> properties

Comment: Would you please give an example of such a plot and how you create the PDF?